# Views slideshow fields

Tags: views

I have an image field in my content type and I want to make a slideshow using the [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module to show one image at a time.

If I put each image in a node of its own, the slideshow works fine. But can I have a slideshow using multiple images from the same field in the same node?

The point of this is that it is easier / quicker to create one node with 10 images than to create 10 different nodes. So far the slideshow seems to load all 10 images at the same time, but I want it to display only one image at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question, but I wonder if the [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module can do what you're trying to achieve. Therefor you may want to consider the alternative modules, as detailed below.

## Use the jCarousel module

Your question seems to be a variation of "[Help with a Slideshow of Multiple Images in a Single Node](https://www.drupal.org/node/679460)", in which the [Views Carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewscarousel) module was recommended as a possible solution/alternative.

However the successor of that module in D7 is the [jCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module. So maybe you want to give that module a try?

## Use the Field Slideshow module

Another module to consider as an alternative, is the [Field Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) module. Here is a quote about it from its project page:

> Provides a Slideshow formatter for Image fields, using JQuery [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin.
>
> Compared to Views slideshows, building the slideshow from multiple nodes, this module builds it from a single node, with a multi-valued Image/Media/Field Collection field.

This excerpt seems like pretty close to what is contained in the question details, no?

Curious to hear if either of these modules help somehow ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try some more but so far I don't see how the jCarousel module avoids my original problem. The Field Slideshow works perfectly but with one drawback - as mentioned here https://www.drupal.org/node/1065292 I don't think the image can have a url (eg click on the image for more info). So it looks like if the images don't need a link then I can use a single node and the Field Slideshow module but if the images do need a link then it is back to individual nodes and the Views slideshow module.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [flex slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider).

Flex Slider module integrates the Flex Slider library with Drupal and several contributed modules which allows you to build responsive, resizable slideshows. Meaning the slideshows automatically adapt to the size of the browser window or device

### FlexSlider features

- Using Fields and Views with FlexSlider
- sliders as navigation for other sliders
- Using carousels
- Using captions